# How can I read and write index properties of a type in .NET via reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a type that has index properties which I want to access via reflection. How can I do that? I suppose an index property is retrievable as a normal property but I have no idea how to get to it by the means of standard reflection. Also, if I have multiple index properties with different signatures like in the following code, is it possible to access each of them?

```
public class IndexType
{
   // Assume some sensible implementation of the getters/setters

   public object this[int index] { get; set; }

   public object this[string key] { get; set; }

   public object this[int index, string key] { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: take a look at http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10007707/using-reflection-reading-the-properties-of-an-object.aspx

Comment: The name of the indexer property is "Item".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to differentiate an index property by the fact that it requires index parameters.  This linq query should do that by checking the `GetIndexParameters` method.

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> indexProperties = 
    O.GetType().GetProperties().Where(pi => pi.GetIndexParameters().Any());
```

Differentiating which is which can be done by inspecting the numbers and type of parameters.

After providing a sensible implementation of your index properties, this code:

```
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in indexProperties) {
            foreach (ParameterInfo parm in pi.GetIndexParameters()) {
                Console.WriteLine(parm.ParameterType.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Yields:

```
System.Int32

System.String

System.Int32
System.String

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. And the linq code looks neat :)